# Duplicate entries created when appending column to array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I am new to Python and could use some help. Essentially I am trying to scrape code from a hockey league website so I can pull it into Excel to see if all the teams in my division have an equal amount of late time slots.

I wrote some code to scrape the games from each of the teams in the division. There are 10 teams and each team has 16 games so there should be 160 results. The entries are getting duplicated somehow and I am getting 320 results.

I think this is happening because I am trying to append the team name to an array that holds the parsed data I scraped before writing it to a Pandas DataFrame. When I remove the code to add the name to the dataset in the array I get the expected amount of results (160), but then my dataset doesn't have the team name associated with each game.

I know I could just delete the duplicate data, but I am trying to understand why I am getting this duplicate data and how I could fix the code to avoid this.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#define list of teams
teamIDs = np.array([[11954, "A Warthog"], [11945, "Blast"], [11951, "Cobra Kai"], [11947, "Homer's Heroes"], [11946, "Hudson Dusters"], [11952, "Le National"], [11948, "Les Boys"], [11953, "Molar Bears"], [11949, "NYAC"], [11950, "Top Shelf"]])

#define dataframe to store data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','day','time', 'teamname'])

#loop through team pages based on teamIDs stored in array to scrape data
for num in range(len(teamIDs)):
    r = requests.get('https://apps.dashplatform.com/dash/index.php?Action=team/index&company=chelsea&teamid={}'.format(teamIDs[num][0]))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    #loop through all game entries on the page and add them to the dataframe
    for li in soup.find_all('li'):
            try:
                #find <li> tags with specific class that holds data points as a string
                gameentry = li.find('h4', class_='list-group-item-heading').text

                #split string apart and assign to array
                games = gameentry.split()

                #add team name to array
                games.append(teamIDs[num][1])

                #add result to the dataframe
                df.loc[df.shape[0]] = games

            except AttributeError:
                continue

#output dataframe to excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Hey, I ran your script and I got 160 results.

Comment: I too got 160 results.

Answer (score 0):

I got 160 results. Please recheck once again. on a different topic, I did some changes to your script to look simple. you don't need to use Excelwriter for a single page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#define list of teams
teamIDs = [11954,11945,11951,11947,11946,11952,11948,11953,11949,11950]

#define dataframe to store data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','day','time', 'teamname'])

#loop through team pages based on teamIDs stored in a list to scrape data
for num in teamIDs:
    r = requests.get('https://apps.dashplatform.com/dash/index.php?Action=team/index&company=chelsea&teamid={}'.format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    Team_Name = soup.find('h2').get_text().replace('Team','')
    #loop through all game entries on the page and add them to the dataframe
    for gameentry in soup.find_all('h4',{'class':'list-group-item-heading'}):
                #split string apart and assign to array
                games = gameentry.text.split()
                #add team name to list
                games.append(Team_Name)
                #add result to the dataframe
                df.loc[df.shape[0]] = games

df.to_excel(r'output.xlsx',index = False)#bydefault sheetname = sheet1
```

Comment: Strange, not sure why that's not happening. Thanks for wewriting the code to be more efficient. @Bhanu Tez can I ask why you used a replace function on the code pulling the team name?  `Team_Name = soup.find('h2').get_text().replace('Team','')`

Comment: so... for example, without replace the Team_Name will be  " Team A Warthog" or " Team Blast". Since we dont want string "Team" in it we are replacing it with ''.